# How would I make a web page print exactly the same across all browsers/printers?

Tags: html, css, printing, cross-browser

Ok, so I'm pretty sure this isn't even possible, but I have a friend whose client is basically begging him for an answer on this so I told him I'd get some input from the friendly folks here at SO.

His client is ULTRA-PICKY about pixel precise user interface design across all browsers (IE7+, FF, Chrome and Safari). They have TEAMS of people in other countries who do nothing but sit there and measure to make sure everything matches their UX style guide down to the pixel in all browsers/versions (fonts, spacings between EVERYTHING, margins, etc).

Having said that, their next request is that they want to print driving directions but their UX requirements are just as stringent for printing. They want margins to be exactly the same on all pages, spacing between elements to be the same, etc. In other words, the printout should be EXACTLY the same, down to the pixel, no matter which browser you print from or printer you print on (aren't you glad this isn't your client)? :)

No, they want nothing to do with PDF, lol.

My question is: is this even possible? If it IS possible, can you point to some online references we can check out? Wouldn't each printer render things a bit differently based on default settings? Aren't there things outside the developer's control here when it comes to printing? Neither I nor my colleague have ever been asked to create something so precise across different browsers/printers so I though I'd get some input here.

Comment: Your friend's client should buy a time machine, and try again in 10 years. Oops, never mind. That's unrealistic.

Comment: Might be more realistic than the client's actual request though. :)

Comment: What's wrong with PDF?  There are a few tools that directly translate to PDF (like wkhtmltopdf, which uses webkit from the server so it will always generate the same PDF regardless of a client's browser), which could easily be printed from... I know they want nothing to do with PDF (so they say), but *why* do they say that?  We use PDF printing for our code-generated invoices and it's worked great.  Do they have an actual reason for not wanting to print from PDF?  Chrome can open PDF's right in the browser and print it perfectly from there.  Firefox has an addon to do the same.

Comment: Imo, part of working with clients is *client education*.  What's possible, what isn't, what work-arounds are available.  If the client is really this unreasonable, find new ones!  This is probably pie-in-the-sky and not an option... but still, clients need to be under the right expectations.

Comment: @nzifnab: What's wrong with HTML & CSS.

Comment: @reisio Usually nothing, but it's possible browser inconsistencies would render not-quite the results you want.  We use HTML and CSS to make the page... then if someone wants to print it we feed that HTML and CSS to wkhtmltopdf which makes a PDF.  It was very easy to implement, and didn't require us to programmatically generate PDF's ourself.

Comment: Yes you said — but why not just print the web page itself.

Comment: @nzifnab nothing is wrong with PDF, IMO. I prefer it, but that's not what they want. This company is in the top 10 of the Fortune 100, so "client education" is futile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render everything to an image (since you said no PDF)?

In all reality, this is an unreasonable request.  You can create styles for different mediums, and handle browser differences with CSS resets and javascript, but you will always have different screen resolutions or screen types (eInk kindles come to mind) and printers with different inks or different types of printers.

Comment: Even an image/PDF will not print the same on all printers. I saw differences of more than 5mm with same program settings due to printer  /driver limitations.